# Scala @tailrec 'Recursive call not in tail position' with return value

Tags: scala, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to initialize binary tree using recursion.

```
@tailrec
def expressionToTreeNodeConversion(expression:String): TreeNode = {

    var chars = expression.toCharArray

    var operatorIndex = findIndexOfMiddleOperator(chars)
    var isOperator = true
    while(operatorIndex==(-1) & isOperator) {

      if (!(chars.contains(OPEN_BRACKET_CHAR) | chars.contains(CLOSE_BRACKET_CHAR)))
        isOperator = false
      else {
        chars = chars.slice(1, chars.length-1)
        operatorIndex = findIndexOfMiddleOperator(chars)
      }
    }

    //If this is an operand
    if (!isOperator)
      return new OperandNode(chars.mkString(""))

    //If this is an operator, recursively call for sub nodes
    val  node = chars(operatorIndex).toString match {
      case AND => new AndNode()
      case OR => new OrNode()
    }

    node.left = expressionToTreeNodeConversion(chars.slice(0, operatorIndex).mkString(""))
    node.right = expressionToTreeNodeConversion(chars.slice(operatorIndex + 1, chars.length).mkString(""))

    node
}
```

I get the error: "Recursive call not in tail position".

The difference here from other recursion example I saw, is that I need to call the recursive method twice, put the return values as right/left, and then return the node it self.

I tried to add the node a constructor that receive left & right, but I still get the same error. (although this is the last operation in the method)

```
val  node = chars(operatorIndex).toString match {
  case AND => new AndNode(expressionToTreeNodeConversion(chars.slice(0, operatorIndex).mkString("")),expressionToTreeNodeConversion(chars.slice(operatorIndex + 1, chars.length).mkString("")))
  case OR => new OrNode(expressionToTreeNodeConversion(chars.slice(0, operatorIndex).mkString("")),)
}
```

Is it even possible to use the @tailrec annotation for my needs?

Comment: You still call the recursive method twice in `case AND` though.

Comment: "although this is the last operation in the method" – No, it is not. The last operation is `new AndNode` or `new OrNode`, respectively. (Actually, the last operation is the assignment to `node`, which happens even after that.)

Answer (score 7):

For a function to be tail recursive, the statement that produces the return value has to either be the final value or the function itself. The reason for this is that tail recursion sets up a trampoline where it acts as if the function had actually exited, and unwinds the call stack, but captures the values necessary for the recursive call so that it can call the method.

Traditional recursive calls will maintain the call stack as it recurses because it needs the stack when the recursive call returns. This will lead to a stack overflow, based on the size of the stack for each call and the number of recursive calls.

Tail recursive avoids this by being able to discard the call stack since it never has to come back to the original caller's context.

In order for your method to become tail recursive, it would have to maintain position in your tree and walk each branch one at a time (like a *depth-first* or *breadth-first* search), passing along the accumulator and position tracking, so that you can determine where to continue once you reach a leaf node. Then the call can become the exit condition of your recursive function.

Comment: Thanks Arne for the explanation and suggestion. I tried editing my code but it became too complex. I think that for my needs of initializing binary tree, @tailrec annotation cannot be useful.